# What is the proper file path for Bootstrap 2.3.2 Glyphicons?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons, twitter-bootstrap-2

I've beens searching around, and I see a ton of different proposed file paths, none of which work for me.

What do I change `background-image: url("/../img/glyphicons-halflings.png");` to?

Comment: where do you put the png file within your project?

Comment: `/Users/adamzerner/collegeanswerz/app/assets/images/glyphicons-halflings.png`

Comment: If you didn't do something fancy to your assets settings then it should be `/assets/glyphicons-halflings.png`. Typically people will put things that they didn't write themselves in `vendor/assets` by the way.

Comment: it's working, thanks! if you want to write it up, I'll give you a Best Answer.

Comment: btw, for my information, how come the proper path skips over images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, if you use [Rails assets pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) all your assets will be compiled to `/assets` folder. There is also an option to change the folder name. Please refer to the guide for more details.

If you use `scss` with [sass-rails](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails) gem there are helper methods [`asset-url` and `image-url`](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/blob/master/README.md#features) that can help you manage with assets path for your `CSS`.

Lastly there are a couple gems you can use to include bootstrap in your Rails app:

https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails is a `less` version (Bootstrap is built with less). It requires `less-rails` gem and https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass